# Как подключить jest к проекту на react + ts vite?

Tags: babel, testng, jest, vite

Пробовал как написано в доке jest но так у меня не работает. Постоянно вылетают ошибки то от бабеля то ts, то что-то с модулями, jsx, проблемы с import. Короче ад какой-то

```
jest.config.js
/**  @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};

babel.config.js

  module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
};

vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import VitePluginSass from 'vite-plugin-sass';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), VitePluginSass()],
});

package.json

    {
  "name": "kanban-board",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "lint:fix": "yarn lint --fix",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-select": "^5.0.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.14.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.8",
    "vite-plugin-sass": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```